# Why DB_ID() function can't be used in DBCC PAGE function

Tags: sql-server

The below code works showing the current database in use as output

```
SELECT DB_ID(),DB_NAME()
```

But is given a Syntax error `Msg 102, Incorrect syntax near '('.` when DB_ID() function is used as below

```
DBCC PAGE(DB_ID(),1,1,3)
```

I tried `DBCC PAGE(select DB_ID() ,1,1,3)` but it isn't also allowed.

Why is it? Is using the variables only way to pass current Database as parameter to DBCC PAGE as below?

```
    DECLARE @DBId INT
SELECT @DBId=DB_ID() 
DBCC PAGE(@DBId ,1,6,3)  WITH TABLERESULTS
```

Comment: it's that it doesn't accept an expression. A variable is treated as a literal value, where as `DB_ID()` is not. You couldn't, for example, do `DBCC PAGE (10-2,1,6,3)` either. It's not just DBCC that has that "limitation"; you can't pass an expression to an stored procedure either. Sometime like `EXEC dbo.MyProc @MyDate = GETDATE();` or `EXEC dbo.MyProc @MyDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, '20190808'));` will fail too.

Comment: *Sometimes* 0 is used to indicate the current database in console commands so perhaps DBCC PAGE(0,1,1,3) will have the same effect.

Comment: @RossBush The 0 worked in DBCC PAGE to refer to the current Database. Thank you! This would save us from variable usage.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for the explanation. After studying your reply, studied more about inability to pass Scalar Function as parameter to SProc. And in the course, another question sprouted if DBCC PAGE is a SProc or a Function @ [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426934/is-dbcc-command-a-sproc-or-a-function)